# cannot import name 'eval_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=4503s)

but after running `from object_detection.utils import config_util`
and `from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2`
I'm getting  this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'eval_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (C:\Users\thepl\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)`
and this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'pipeline_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (C:\Users\thepl\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)` respectively.

I've checked the directory given and it only has init.py and pychance

currently in a conda environment

EDIT: did the `Protobuf Installation/Compilation` section of [this tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install) which I downloaded into the directory mentioned above, restarted my computer. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi @Magma, this error you are encountering with the import statements from object_detection.protos indicates that the necessary Protocol Buffers (protobuf) files are not properly complied or accessible. and It seems like the Protobuf files for the Object Detection API are not properly compiled or accessible. This can lead to the ImportError you are encountering when trying to import pipeline_pb2 and eval_pb2.